# Excel api, but where to store the data

Tags: python, sqlite

Morning,

I have dynamic data which is updated either daily, weekly or monthly in excel (this is the only api link). However, for use in python, is it better to keep the data stored in excel or transfer it to SQLite and access it from there?

Or is there a more efficient way of managing this process?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you really need (see below, formulae). KISS (Keep it stupid simple) way is often the good one.

Some Python API like xlwt and xlrd can read and write Excel files :
http://www.python-excel.org/

But xlwt and xlrd can't evaluate formulae. If you need formulae, try openpyxl http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/2.5/

Comment: thanks, so the best way to store the data would be keep it in excel and use from there?